# Differentiate between My SQL Queries

Tags: php, mysql

What is the difference between the following queries? They give me the same result.

**1**

```
SELECT student. * ,
department.department_name,
semester.semester_name
FROM (
student
LEFT JOIN department ON student.student_id = department.department_id
LEFT JOIN semester ON student.student_id = semester.semester_id
)
```

**2**

```
SELECT student. * ,
department.department_name,
semester.semester_name
FROM (
student
LEFT JOIN department ON student.department_id = department.department_id
LEFT JOIN semester ON student.semester_id = semester.semester_id
)
```

**3**

```
SELECT student. * ,
department.department_name,
semester.semester_name
FROM (
student
LEFT JOIN department ON student.student_id = student.student_id
LEFT JOIN semester ON student.student_id = student.student_id
)
```

**4**

```
SELECT student. * , department.department_name, semester.semester_name
FROM (
student
LEFT JOIN department ON student.department_id = student.student_id
LEFT JOIN semester ON student.semester_id = student.student_id
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2) (unless you have a weird schema) would be correct in that it would give a list of students and their courses and semesters.

3) would give a list of students against *all* courses and *all* semesters since `student.student_id = student.student_id` will always be true.

1 and 4) Will give random matchings between students and courses and semesters depending on which ids happen to tally between them (i.e. where they student id happens to be the same as the semester or department id).

Answer (score 3):

You can't match this:

```
student.student_id = department.department_id
```

It doesn't make sense - you are saying that a student ID and a department number are interchangeable, but they are not. In this particular case, you probably have "student 1" and "department 1", and so in the case you are testing, it works. But it will not in general.

Equally, there is no value in doing this:

```
student.student_id = student.student_id
```

Here you are saying that you want the rows where something is equal to itself. Since all things are equal to themselves this will not apply any limitation, and so is redundant. If this is the only clause to a `JOIN` you will end up joining to all rows of the new table (a Cartesian product), which is definitely not what you want.

Only query (2) appears to be correct.

Comment: NULL = NULL in MySQL appears to return NULL,  not True: dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: @BLaZuRE, that's a good point for the general comparison case, but I should imagine these primary/foreign keys would all be defined as `NOT NULL`?

Comment: Since the question is so basic, I wouldn't count on these tables having primary/foreign keys as expected and wouldn't count on them being defined as `NOT NULL`.  I also wanted to emphasize that *not all things* are equal to themselves.  Similarly, if you try a where clause `SELECT ... WHERE colX = value UNION SELECT ... WHERE colX <> value`, you may not get all the rows because you also need `WHERE colX IS NULL`.  I found this out the hard way but beginners should be aware.